# php rename swap file names doesnt reload image

Tags: php, rename, swap

i am working on a website that has a set of images and 1st image is like an avatar.. when i want to change the avatar (1st picture) what i do is i swap the 1st image name with the new image that i want to use as avatar.
I do this on an ajax function so i dont need to refresh the page after i do that.

```
rename("C:/wamp/www/invest/Coded/oferte/" . $offer_id . "/" . $pic_name, "C:/wamp/www/invest/Coded/oferte/" . $offer_id . "/" . $temp_name);
rename("C:/wamp/www/invest/Coded/oferte/" . $offer_id . "/" . $avafile, "C:/wamp/www/invest/Coded/oferte/" . $offer_id . "/" . $pic_name);
rename("C:/wamp/www/invest/Coded/oferte/" . $offer_id . "/" . $temp_name, "C:/wamp/www/invest/Coded/oferte/" . $offer_id . "/" . $avafile);
```

My problem is after i do that, i delete the images from the div and i add them again in the new order, but i think the browser saves the images somewhere and dont reload them and they appear in same order. Only after i refresh the page, they appear in the right order.
Is there like a solution to make the browser upload the images again ?

Thank you in advance, Daniel!

EDIT: This is the ajax function:

```
function avaPic(offer_id, pic_name, onFinish) {
    var request;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     else
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            onFinish();
        }
    }

    request.open("GET", "php/script.php?action=avaPic&offer_id=" + offer_id + "&pic_name=" + pic_name, true);
    request.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
    request.send();
}
```

and this is the php:

```
if($action == "avaPic") {
        $offer_id = $_GET["offer_id"];
        $pic_name = $_GET["pic_name"];
        $filearray = getDirectoryList("C:/wamp/www/invest/Coded/oferte/" . $offer_id . "/");
        $avafile = $filearray[0];
        $temp_name = "temp.jpg";

        rename("C:/wamp/www/invest/Coded/oferte/" . $offer_id . "/" . $pic_name, "C:/wamp/www/invest/Coded/oferte/" . $offer_id . "/" . $temp_name);
        rename("C:/wamp/www/invest/Coded/oferte/" . $offer_id . "/" . $avafile, "C:/wamp/www/invest/Coded/oferte/" . $offer_id . "/" . $pic_name);
        rename("C:/wamp/www/invest/Coded/oferte/" . $offer_id . "/" . $temp_name, "C:/wamp/www/invest/Coded/oferte/" . $offer_id . "/" . $avafile);
    }
```

on the onFinish function, i refresh the div wih the images in hope they reorder again in the new order, but they appear same as they were before, untill i refresh the page

I found it, how to force the browser reload the images.

```
<div>
       <img src="img1.jpg" />
       <img src="img2.jpg" />
       <img src="img3.jpg" />
</div>
```

instead this, i have to generate a html code with a time parameter in order to make browser reload the images. like this `<img src='"img1.jpg?" + d.getTime()' />`

Comment: If you want to display a different image, then you should change the code that generates the image tag markup to set the src to a different filename.  Renaming the files is a really bad way of doing this.

Comment: can you be more specific pls, i couldnt understand your idea. i have in a folder ex: img1.jpg, img2.jpg, img3.jpg and 1st is avatar(img1.jpg). If i want to change the avatar to img3.jpg i was trying to swap the names img3.jpg with img1.jpg so img3.jpg will be the 1st image therefore the avatar. The problem is the images have same names so i think browser dont reload them since they have it loaded in the background. If you find another solution of how i could achieve this, it will be welcomed :)

Comment: could you post the javascript code you are using?

Comment: there is nothing should how you are replacing  the `div` or `img` on the current page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check will this solved your issue,
If you have your HTML like this,

```
        <div>
           <img src="abc.jpg" />
           <img src="abc.jpg" />
           <img src="abc.jpg" />
        </div>
```

Just run this jquery after your ajax call

```
        $('div img').attr("src",$('img').attr("src")+"?+"Math.random())
```

Comment: there is a way to do it, to change all the image names so they need to be loaded again, but i need to give them new names but in same alfabetical order so they have the same order, and i thought there is an easier approach